# Highcharts datalables enabled for one series and one point on the chart via chart function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

One point on my bubble chart that I want to enable a dataLabels for. This is the highest value in my series. At the end of my chart code I have a function that i used to handle some point states but datalables don't work and I can't seem to find an example on how to turn it on.

```
function(chart) {
  chart.series[0].data[1].setState('select');
  chart.series[0].data[1].dataLabels().enabled = true;
}
```

So the first one works (setState), no issues there (so I know I'm close) but the second one doesn't work.

FYI, The series and data point will never change from series 0 and data point 1. So I don't need a reusable fix this time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use callback function to do this. Instead of that you just need to define the `series.dataLabels.formatter` function for specific series. I prepared the example, where the `formatter` function returns the data label only for the highest value of the series. Here is the code:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Series 1',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {     
             var highest = Math.max.apply(null, this.series.yData)
             return this.y === highest ? highest : ''
        }
    }
}
```

You can see how it works on this example: https://jsfiddle.net/upLpj0tk/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter